# Нуждается ли Jackson ObjectMapper в пометке классов как Serializable?

Tags: java, json, сериализация, jackson

Есть сущности, которые сериализуются в/из JSON с помощью Jackson `ObjectMapper`.

Нужно ли помечать такие классы интерфейсом `Serializable`, либо это пережиток стандартных средств сериализации java? Возможны ли проблемы в противном случае?

Comment: Кто такие сущности, в жсоне таких нет?

Comment: @RomanC имеются в виду обычные DTO классы, которые служат именно для сериалицаии. По сути это POJO

Comment: Для жексона serializable не нужен. Да и вообще для любой другой библиотеки json скорей всего тоже не нужен. Они же все работают на уровне бинов и рефлексии. Так что нужно ли ваши сущности помечать или не нужно, будет зависеть от других "потребителей". Например jpa требует сериализацию (правда непонятно для чего. не разбирался:).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Serializable используется java.io и необходим, если вы хотите сохранить объекты в сеансе. Некоторые другие фреймворки используют Serializable за сценой для выполнения сериализации. Если вы не знаете, где сериализуется объект с помощью java.io.Serializable, лучше добавить этот интерфейс в DTO.

На стороне клиента может использоваться другая сериализация, такая как JSON, XML и т. д.,  и в этом случае используется Jackson,  но она не влияет на процессы, выполняющие сериализацию на стороне сервера, и она должна обрабатываться отдельно вашим кодом или некоторыми другими средами, такими как Struts или Spring, не так ли, не имеет значения.